# Ruby Gems C extension example not working

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-c-extension

I am trying to follow this tutorial on building c extension in ruby gems http://guides.rubygems.org/gems-with-extensions/.

I have the following files:

#### ext/my_malloc/extconf.rb

```
require "mkmf"

abort "missing malloc()" unless have_func "malloc"
abort "missing free()"   unless have_func "free"

create_makefile "my_malloc/my_malloc"
```

#### ext/my_malloc/my_malloc.c

```
#include <ruby.h>

struct my_malloc {
  size_t size;
  void *ptr;
};

static void
my_malloc_free(void *p) {
  struct my_malloc *ptr = p;

  if (ptr->size > 0)
    free(ptr->ptr);
}

static VALUE
my_malloc_alloc(VALUE klass) {
  VALUE obj;
  struct my_malloc *ptr;

  obj = Data_Make_Struct(klass, struct my_malloc, NULL, my_malloc_free, ptr);

  ptr->size = 0;
  ptr->ptr  = NULL;

  return obj;
}

static VALUE
my_malloc_init(VALUE self, VALUE size) {
  struct my_malloc *ptr;
  size_t requested = NUM2SIZET(size);

  if (0 == requested)
    rb_raise(rb_eArgError, "unable to allocate 0 bytes");

  Data_Get_Struct(self, struct my_malloc, ptr);

  ptr->ptr = malloc(requested);

  if (NULL == ptr->ptr)
    rb_raise(rb_eNoMemError, "unable to allocate %ld bytes", requested);

  ptr->size = requested;

  return self;
}

static VALUE
my_malloc_release(VALUE self) {
  struct my_malloc *ptr;

  Data_Get_Struct(self, struct my_malloc, ptr);

  if (0 == ptr->size)
    return self;

  ptr->size = 0;
  free(ptr->ptr);

  return self;
}

void
Init_my_malloc(void) {
  VALUE cMyMalloc;

  cMyMalloc = rb_const_get(rb_cObject, rb_intern("MyMalloc"));

  rb_define_alloc_func(cMyMalloc, my_malloc_alloc);
  rb_define_method(cMyMalloc, "initialize", my_malloc_init, 1);
  rb_define_method(cMyMalloc, "free", my_malloc_release, 0);
}
```

I do the following to build the extension:

```
$ cd ext/my_malloc
$ ruby extconf.rb
checking for malloc()... yes
checking for free()... yes
creating Makefile
$ make
compiling my_malloc.c
linking shared-object my_malloc.bundle
$ cd ../..
$ ruby -Ilib:ext -r my_malloc -e "p MyMalloc.new(5).free"
```

However, I get the following error on the last command:

```
/Users/Daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.6/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- my_malloc (LoadError)
from     
/Users/Daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.6/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Note, I'm using rbenv, I've tried running rbenv rehash and I'm running version 2.1.6.

Comment: `-Ilib:ext` -> `-Ilib/ext`?

Comment: the error still occurs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct shell command is:

```
ruby -Iext/my_malloc -r my_malloc -e "p MyMalloc.new(5).free"
```

The code also has some other mistakes. Correct

```
rb_raise(rb_eNoMemError, "unable to allocate %ld bytes", requested);
```

to

```
rb_raise(rb_eNoMemError, "unable to allocate %" PRIuSIZE " bytes", requested);
```

since `requested` has type `size_t` and not `long` (`PRIuSIZE` is non-standard and defined in `"ruby/ruby.h"`). And

```
cMyMalloc = rb_const_get(rb_cObject, rb_intern("MyMalloc"));
```

to

```
cMyMalloc = rb_define_class("MyMalloc", rb_cObject);
```

to actually define the `MyMalloc` class.

Comment: Thanks.  Fyi, changing to PRIuSIZE throws a warning on make `warning: data argument not used by format string [-Wformat-extra-args]`.

Comment: Fixed it. The `%`. character was missing.